# How do I find out memory requirement when deploy Python sample to Bluemix?

Tags: python, memory-management, deployment, ibm-cloud

I am following the example to deploy sample python application to bluemix
[BLUEMIX-PYTHON-FLASK-SAMPLE](https://github.com/IBM-Bluemix/bluemix-python-flask-sample)

Created project successfully
Cloned repository successfully
Configured pipeline successfully
Deploy to BLUEMIX failed.

I checked the error in deployment log, seem to complain about `memory limit exceeded, Server error, status code:400, error code 100005`.

How do I add the statement in the sample app to output the memory requirement so that I will know how much it is needed?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have exceeded the max app limit on your Bluemix account.

Login to your Bluemix account and check if all the app memory limit is utilized.  If you have reached your limit then you might have to remove one or more of the apps which you are not using based on how much memory space is needed.

in the python-flask-sample example guide, it is mentioned.

`cf push your-app-name -m 128M`

You can also lower the memory for your app by running the following.

`cf scale your-app-name -m 128M`

So 128 M will be allocated to this app while deploying on Bluemix, so ideally freeing 128 M should be good enough to get rid of the error you are seeing. This memory limit can be changed as needed.

Additionally, this limit is only during the free trial phase.  Once you enter your credit card there is no limit.

Answer (score 3):

The memory limit is controlled by the memory value in the manifest.yml file in the root of the project. You don't need to have this manifest.yml file present as Bluemix will define defaults for you. In this case the memory allocation would be 1GB as this is the default which is really to much for a sample app like this.

I have just committed a change to the github project [bluemix-python-flask-sample](https://github.com/IBM-Bluemix/bluemix-python-flask-sample) which adds the [manifest.yml](https://github.com/IBM-Bluemix/bluemix-python-flask-sample/blob/master/manifest.yml) file with a memory value of 128M. You should pull the new changes or just use the 'Deploy to Bluemix' button either on the github page or here:

[image: Deploy to Bluemix]

Answer (score 1):

This issue is mostly due to insufficient memory available, which you can verify using your bluemix dashboard.

On the dashboard the first widget represents how much memory you have available and how much you are using,

if deploying an app would go over this limit then you will not be able to do so.

For More [details](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/24373/error-deploying-the-sample-application-exceeded-organizations-memory-limit.html).