# IBM NodeRED App Deploy Error - Memory Limit Exceeded error state: 400, error code: 100005

Tags: websphere, cloud-foundry

I'm having issues to perform NodeRED App deploy after a package.json modification to add a Dashboard and IBM Input and Output. The log states that I exceeded the memory limit of my organization, with the error msg:
**Error restarting application: Server error, status code: 400, error code: 100005, message: You have exceeded your organization's memory limit: app requested more memory than available**

Which is not true, so, I've tried to reduce the memory and app instances, as sugested here:
https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/cloud-foundry-public?topic=cloud-foundry-public-ts-cf-apps

And also tried to delete all and start all over. But nothing seems to work.

The code added to package.json is:

```
"node-red-dashboard":"^2.22.1",
"node-red-contrib-scx-ibmiotapp":"0.0.49"
```

[image: Error Log]

[image: Delivery Pipeline]

[image: Resource List]

Answer (score 1):

I was able to deploy the service after I modified the memory variable to 128MB at the manifest.yml file. The manifest.yml file can be found at the root of your NodeRED repository.

The clue to solve this problem was found here in this post:
[How do I find out memory requirement when deploy Python sample to Bluemix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29859173/how-do-i-find-out-memory-requirement-when-deploy-python-sample-to-bluemix)

Thanks to whitfiea